# Does boost.asio's ssl::stream encrypt messages?

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, boost-asio

I'm connecting a server and client using boost.asio's `ssl` facilities. I create a `boost::asio::ssl::stream`, load up a self-signed certificate on the server and client, load the certificate's private key on the server, and successfully perform the `handshake()`.

I believe now that `boost::asio::ssl::stream::write_some()` (and its `async` and `read` variants) will automatically encrypt and decrypt messages for me. However, [the documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__stream.html) doesn't confirm this.

If there is encryption, is this asymmetric encryption with the server's public key, or symmetric encryption with a session key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It encrypts the messages but only in transit. That's what transport encryption means.

It wouldn't be in the documentation, because it's a property of SSL/TLS which does document it.

In fact the stream's read/write operations are invalid to use before `handshake` or  after `shutdown`.

To learn more about SSL: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Comment: and it is symmetric key encryption, correct? I want to be sure I can use the key as a "session key" after user authentication.

Comment: I am asking because the [example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/ssl/server.cpp) uses pre-generated Diffie-Hellman keys for... something. So I was worried keys may be reused.

Comment: DH are for key exchange. The wiki page should give you all the details. Or, I can highly recommand David Wong's new ["Real Life Cryptography"](https://www.manning.com/books/real-world-cryptography) which covers it in an light chapter. I just noticed another article on the publisher's site: [How Does Transport Layer Security Work](https://freecontent.manning.com/how-does-tls-work/)

Comment: User authentication has little or nothing to do with TLS. It's also unclear what you mean by "the key". There are multiple keys involved in the protocol and few of them should concern you (they're implementation details). Even if you found a key that you could repurpose, it would probably be a bad idea to do so. In general, have (or derive) different keys for different purposes.